# How to remove the plus sign inside a div (but not the minus sign) with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I get three kind of values in a div:

With plus sign:

```
<div class="thumblock ">
+2
<div class="ratingtext ">
<div class="raterclear"></div>
</div>
</h4>
<span>votes</span>
</div>
```

With minus sign:

```
<div class="thumblock ">
-2
<div class="ratingtext ">
<div class="raterclear"></div>
</div>
</h4>
<span>votes</span>
</div>
```

and no signs:

```
<div class="thumblock ">
0
<div class="ratingtext ">
<div class="raterclear"></div>
</div>
</h4>
<span>votes</span>
```

How to remove the plus sign inside the `.thumblock` div  with jQuery?

**EDIT:**

```
<div class="thumblock">
    <div id="gdsr_thumb_text_137_a" class="gdt-size-20 voted inactive gdthumbtext">
      <span class="rating-result">2</span>
    </div>

    <div class="ratingtext">
      <div id="gdsr_thumb_137_a_up" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumb gdup">
        <div class="gdt-starrating"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="gdsr_thumb_137_a_dw" class="gdt-size-20 gdthumb gddw">
        <div class="gdt-starrating"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="raterclear"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Ryan For some reason it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it..

```
$('.thumblock').html(function(i, oldhtml) {
  return oldhtml.replace('+','');
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Nctg5/

---

***note** : You have an invalid `h4` closing tag (without opening it)*

---

**Update**

Use this, since you have other plugins working with the same content..

```
$('.thumblock')
    .contents()
    .filter( function(){
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).each(function(){
        this.nodeValue= this.nodeValue.replace(/\+/g,'');
    });
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Nctg5/3/

Comment: this worked just perfect (I didn't paste the opening h2 tag).

Comment: Strange, for some reason after adding that code I can't vote any more (GD star rating).

Comment: @alexchenco, not really strange.. The original code was re-writing the html, and that removed all active events on the inner elements.. **Use the code in the update instead**..

Comment: Hey sorry but how should I modify that function if the output was changed as the **EDIT** above?

Answer (score 1):

Tested and demod here: http://jsfiddle.net/JrhGy/1/

```
$('.thumblock').html(function(k,html){
    return html.replace(/^\s*\+/,'');
})
```

Has advantage of not interfering with other `+` signs = will only replace leading `+` sign in the content.

Comment: very strange, some of the answers which work here, break the voting function (Wordpress' GD star rating plugin).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thumblock').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).text().replace('+', '');
    $(this).text(value);
});
```

This iterates through the divs, replaces only the + signs with an empty string, and sets the text in the div to the new string.

Comment: .. but this will also remove all the child elements inside the `.thumblock` element..

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$('.thumblock').each(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    $(me).text($(me).text().replace('+',''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

sup alex

so if you have controll over the markupp you shuld but the "operators" in a span
like this

```
<div class="thumblock ">
 <span class="plus">+</span>2
<div class="ratingtext ">

... other

<div class="thumblock ">
 <span class="minus">-</span>2
<div class="ratingtext ">
```

and the code

```
$(".thumblock span.plus").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thumblock').text($(this).replace("+",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".thumblock").each(function(k,v){
    var ele = $(this);
    var eleText = ele.text();
    ele.text(eleText.replace(/\+/g, ""));
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/epXaK/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){

    $('.thumblock').each(function() {

       $(this).text($(this).text().replace('+','') )

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_prasad/q8C4N/2/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would reorganize your html such that I can access just that specific value you are referring to. I would do something like:

```
<div class="thumblock ">
<span class="thumblockspan">+2</span>
<div class="ratingtext ">
<div class="raterclear"></div>
</div>
</h4>
<span>votes</span>
</div>
```

Then, you can do a simple replace(), so something like:

```
var v = $('.thumblockspan').html();
v=v.replace('+','');
$('.thumblockspan').html(v);
```

Or, with one line:

```
$('.thumblockspan').html($('.thumblockspan').html().replace('+',''));
```

Regular expressions are also an option, but for something this simple, replace seems to do the trick :)

Comment: huh, that's odd. i just tried it and it seems to work for me. just use the three line version then ....